# How can I send an HTML e-mail with new Outlook.com web access?

Tags: outlook.com

I have a piece of HTML which I want to send as an e-mail. In previous versions Outlook.com had an option to "edit HTML" but I am not finding anything similar in the latest version. How can I do that now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to add HTML to an email for a browser-based email client is to copy and paste it.  But the catch is, you can't copy and paste the *actual* HTML markup -- you have to capture the *results* of the HTML.

[This article](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/general-miscellaneous/how-to-send-an-html-email-from-gmail/) has a good detailed breakdown of how to copy and paste HTML code into an email.  (Note that for step #1, you don't need an actual HTML editor; you can use any text editor, like Notepad.)

**EDIT:** This method works with mixed results in the Outlook.com email editor.  For example, copying and pasting the Stack Overflow toolbar renders outside the body of the email:

[image]

but other HTML snippets will render inside the body, like this Stack Overflow content:

[image]

However, both examples were able to be sent, and the HTML rendered correctly in the received email (and was functional -- links could be opened).

Comment: Have you tested it with Outlook.com web? This doesn't work for me.

Comment: I've tested it in Yahoo! and Gmail, haven't tested it in Outlook.com yet but I can in about an hour.

Comment: @notGeek I just tested it in Outlook.com and it works with mixed results -- some HTML renders outside the body of the email, but much of it renders inside the body, so you can send it.  I've updated my answer to include a screen shot.

Comment: you're right, it works. my bad. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you know HTML - you can write the raw HTML in an online code editor such as [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zcutqvdL/).

### Insert Horizontal Line Rule for Outlook.com

```
<p>dog</p>
<hr/>
<p>cat</p>
```

Copying the rendered output - you can then paste the rich content into the editor and it will render properly in OWA.

[image]